# Python program that identifies variables of a .py file and prints them

Tags: python, file, variables, local-variables, global

I need to create a program that finds all the variables of .py file(globals and locals) and print them.
But I don't know how to use the function dir() or global()/local() on the other .py file for searching the variables.

Can you help me please?
def identifyVariables(name):

```
file = open (name,'r')
variablesStr = "The variables on code are: \n"
contL=0
for linea in file:
    contL = contL + 1
    pos = linea.find(str(dir()))
    #No se donde meter el for para pegarlo con el po
    if(pos>-1):
                variablesStr += linea[pos+1:len(linea)] + ": line " + contL
file.close()
print(variablesStr)
```

Comment: You're essentially looking for interpreter code. You could read the file as a string and do regex testing against a single ` = ` sign, or you could look for how current Python interpreters identify and store variables. This may provide some insights under the variables section:
https://www.aosabook.org/en/500L/a-python-interpreter-written-in-python.html

Comment: ``dir``, ``globals`` and ``locals`` are for variables of *your* program. They have no knowledge about variables of some program described by code contained in some file that you just happen to be reading.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi ohhhh ok ok thank you so much!!

Comment: @zavtra oh ok, at the beginning I had the same idea of finding the variables by searching '=' but then i thought that it had a lot of more conditions than just having '=' for being a variable and I thought that maybe python had some kind of function or idk...

Answer (score 0):

You want to write "a program that finds *all* the variables". I wanted to warn you in advance that Python is going to make that exceptionally difficult if you care about thoroughness. If you *don't*, like you're just looking for the most common case of `foo = "bar"`, fine: you can use something like [ast.parse](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html#ast.parse) to look for variable assignments, and that will probably get you 99% of the way there.

But if your goal is to find *every* variable in an module, consider this snippet:

```py
vars().update({"spam": "eggs"})

print(spam)
```

The approach of looking for variable assignment won't discover this. Also, consider that a given module may have variables set on it by other things:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> requests.spam
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'spam'
>>> setattr(requests, 'spam', 'eggs')
>>> requests.spam
'eggs'
```

This isn't uncommon for modules that serve as storage for configuration settings and such.

Comment: I don't really understand how ast.parse works can you help me giving me an example or a little more information of how to use it in my case? Thank you! @Kirk Strauser